# Something is counted wrongly in a determinant of block matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

I am counting something wrongly as I am looking at the determinant of a block matrix.

Let us consider this example:
$$
  M = \begin{pmatrix} a & 1^T \\ 1 & I_{n-1}\end{pmatrix}
$$
where $a\neq 0$ is scalar, $1$ is a $n-1$-dimensional vector of ones and $I_{n-1}$ is identity of dimension $(n-1)\times (n-1)$ (will write I).

Now we know that $\left|\begin{matrix} A & B \\ C & D\end{matrix}\right|= \det(A-BD^{-1}C)\det(D)$ if $D$ is invertible.

So let us consider $\det(\lambda I_n-M)=0$ and we get:
\begin{align}
    \left|\lambda I - \begin{pmatrix} a & 1^T \\ 1 & I\end{pmatrix}\right|&=\left|\begin{matrix}\lambda -a & -1^T \\ -1 & (\lambda - 1)I\end{matrix}\right|\\[2ex]
    &\stackrel{(\lambda \neq 1)}{=} \left|\lambda-a - (1/(\lambda-1)(n-1)\right||(\lambda-1)I|=0\qquad (*)
\end{align}
Now here $\lambda\neq 1$ and thus the second factor can never be zero, so the equation is true only if the first scalar is zero, and one can compute that. It results in a second order equation.
For $\lambda=1$ we get that the determinant of $(\lambda I_n-M)$ is indeed zero.

So then it seems that we get two solutions from the first term in $(*)$ and a solution $\lambda=1$ with multiplicity $n-1$ from the second case. This is obviously wrong. I am counting something (an eigenvalue 1) an extra time.

I am baffled as I cannot see where I am failing.

Comment: When $\lambda=1$ your matrix has rank $2$ and hence $\lambda=1$ has multiplicity $n-2$ and NOT $n-1$.

Comment: your function at $(*)$ is not a polynomial but a rational function. If you shift one $(\lambda - 1)$ from $|(\lambda-1)I|$ into the first determinate, you get a polynomial (after simplifying). Now you can start to count multiplicity.